# Как сделать общую переменную для двух фрагментов?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Имеется RecyclerView в Фрагменте №1 и Фрагмент 2 с парой кнопок. Оба фрагменты внутри ViewPager. Из фрагмента №1 нажимая на кнопку я могу добавлять элементы в RecyclerView,но я хочу это делать из Фрагмента №2. То есть по нажатию кнопки во фрагменте создавать один item для Recyclerview и помещать его, при этом не переходя на фрагмент с RecyclerView. Я представляю это так, что надо сделать общий адаптер , устанавливать его во фрагменте с RecyclerView,а добавлять элементы в фрагменте без RecyclerView.Как это лучше сделать?Пока что только идея в том что бы связать их через активность,но там же проблемы будут также

Comment: ничего не понятно вообще

Answer (score 4):

Вы ничего не рассказали про используемый стэк библиотек архитектурных, засим сложно показать вам конкретный код для вашего случая. Однако, видимо, вы ничего из этого не используете. Отсюда проблема - стандартными средствами реализовавывать то что вам нужно - неудобно. А нестандартными - нужно вникать в, скорее всего, незнакомые библиотеки, реализующие определённые паттерны проектирования, которые вы также, возможно не встречали в практике.

Засим вот вам краткое абстрактное описание решения:

1. Создайте синглтон для хранения списка элементов, для отображения в списке.
2. Изменяйте список из нужного места.
3. Уведомляйте об изменениях в списке, чтобы перерисовать экран.

А вот так можно это реализовать с библиотеками:

1. Берём `RxJava`, `RxAndroid`, `RxRelay` + `ToothPick`
2. Создаём класс с `BehaviorRelay<List<Data>>`
3. Биндим его экземпляр как синглтон с помощью ToothPick
4. Инжектим экземпляры класса из п2 в оба фрагмента.
5. Список отображаем, подписавшись на изменения источника данных из п.2
6. Когда нужно, через BehaviorRelay из п2 отправлем новый список данных.

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus а такое ,как вы считаете, может помочь с данной проблемой?

Comment: @Анабель, да, можно и так. Но лично я не советую, т.к. предложенное мною решение более универсальное и использует библиотеки которые и так присутствуют в большинстве проектов. В своей практике я встречал использование этой и либы и переписывал на показанный в ответе подход для унификации кодовой базы.

Comment: В таком случае их впитывание только будет на пользу, благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Не должно быть никаких переменных общих между двумя разными экранами. Если вам необходимо шарить какие-то данные между разными экранами, вы можете создать сущность которая будет жить независимо от этих экранов. Она уже может хранить какое-то состояние.

Тут есть пару вариантов:

- Можно сущность сделать синглтоном. У вас будет единственный экземпляр который может жить на протяжении всего приложения.
- Второй вариант это привязать эту сущность к жизни активити в которой живут фрагменты. Это может быть Presenter или ViewModel или что-то еще, что привязано именно к активити.

Comment: Такие сущности , если их будет достаточно,не сильно нагрузят программу в плане её быстродействия и объёма памяти?

Comment: Ну зависит от того, что в них будет лежать и как вы будет взаимодействовать с ними. Если там будет какой-то небольшой кеш который нужно шарить между экранами, то это одно дело, а если вы там сохраните 200 картинок или тяжелых объектов и еще будете ходить в них на UI потоке, то загрузят. Тут уже база данных нужны. Я ж не знаю какова задача. Но суть в том, что в случае если их просто шарить между экранами через бандлы будет тоже самое

Comment: По сути это тот же самый метод что и изложен во втором ответе на данный вопрос?